# Remote InDesign server entrance to my local folders

Tags: indesign-server

I have used InDesign server locally and in properties, it goes like
`indesign.instance=http://localhost:20055`and works fine.

Now I try to use instances running on a remote server and in properties it goes as follows:

```
indesign.instances=http://##.#.#.11:7700,http://##.#.#.11:7701,http://##.#.#.11:7702
```

and my app connects to the server where InDesign server instances are running. When I execute my script it fails with an error that the file does not exist or cannot find a directory. I understand that instance does not know anything about my file system. But I know for sure it can be connected.

Could you please advise me on the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could share the file system you are working on over a shared folder. Then your Client will place a file into the shared file system and the server can find it.

Or, if it is a remote server without any direct network access, build a document service to upload a file to the server over HTTP.